# Set static space between custom axes

Tags: c#, teechart

I have to have static space (lets say 20 px) between axes.
If I have more axes on the left, it is possible to set their `StartPosition` and `EndPosition` in pixels or in percents.

1. For pixels setting - is there some way, how I can get the height of the space, where are the axes (red line in the picture)?
2. For percents setting - is there some way, how I can automatically convert 20 px to percents? I could calculate that by myself if I know the height, but I don't know how to get it - see 1.

[image: highlighted axes space]

I am able to get the height of the whole panel, where the chart is, but I don't know where to get the actual height of the space for left axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tChart1.Chart.ChartRect` gives you the Rectangle of the "drawing zone". In your case, where you have to get that size before the axes calculations, you can use `GetAxesChartRect` event and use `e.AxesChartRect` as follows:

[image: Chart]

```
private void testChartRect()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    Line line = new Line(tChart1.Chart);
    tChart1.Series.Add(line);
    line.Chart = tChart1.Chart;
    line.FillSampleValues();

    Axis axis = new Axis();
    tChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(axis);
    line.CustomVertAxis = axis;
    axis.AxisPen.Color = line.Color;
    axis.Labels.Font.Color = line.Color;
  }

  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
  tChart1.Panel.MarginLeft = 10;

  //tChart1.AfterDraw += TChart1_AfterDraw1;
  tChart1.GetAxesChartRect += TChart1_GetAxesChartRect;
}

private void TChart1_GetAxesChartRect(object sender, GetAxesChartRectEventArgs e)
{
  Rectangle chartRect = e.AxesChartRect;

  int axisLength = (chartRect.Bottom - chartRect.Top) / tChart1.Axes.Custom.Count;
  int margin = 20;
  for (int i = 0; i < tChart1.Axes.Custom.Count; i++)
  {
    Axis axis = tChart1.Axes.Custom[i];
    axis.StartEndPositionUnits = PositionUnits.Pixels;
    axis.StartPosition = i * axisLength;
    axis.EndPosition = (i + 1) * axisLength - (i != (tChart1.Axes.Custom.Count - 1) ? margin : 0);
  }
}

private void TChart1_AfterDraw1(object sender, Graphics3D g)
{
  tChart1.Graphics3D.Brush.Color = Color.Red;
  tChart1.Graphics3D.Brush.Transparency = 80;
  tChart1.Graphics3D.Rectangle(tChart1.Chart.ChartRect);
}
```

Comment: Where I should work with the `tChart1.Chart.ChartRect`? If I change the position of the axes in the `BeforeDrawAxes` event, the position is still the same (until next redraw), but if I change for example the color of the labels, the color is changed instantly, so where should I change the position of the axes because the `BeforeDrawAxes` event is too late.